# Wordpress posts order by post_title after converting title in to decimal?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In custom query i've found we can convert post title into decimal and then order by that.

Example:

```
    $querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* ,$wpdb->terms.slug

    FROM $wpdb->posts,$wpdb->terms

    WHERE  $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 

    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' 

    AND $wpdb->terms.slug = 'open-houses' 

    ORDER BY convert(`post_title`, decimal) ASC  "; 
   $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
```

This works fine on ordering the post titles but actually doesn't returns the correct results while fetching the posts from specific category (means query is wrong somewhere).

I want to follow word press query standard but along with ORDER BY `convert('post_title', decimal) ASC  ";`  ,

something like

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 , 'order_by'=>'convert(`post_title`, decimal)', 'order' => 'ASC' , 'category_name' => 'cat-slug-here');
$pageposts = get_posts( $args ) ;
```

is it possible? Or any other way?

my data contains `post_title`

- 78 West 85th Street #3A
- 786 West 85th Street #5A
- 252 West 85th Street #4A
- (so on)

After querying the data list should come in order like

- 78 West 85th Street #3A
- 252 West 85th Street #4A
- 786 West 85th Street #5A

Answer (score 0):

To turn the initial strings into numbers try this:

```
$querystr = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* ,$wpdb->terms.slug
    FROM $wpdb->posts,$wpdb->terms
    WHERE  $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post' 
    AND $wpdb->terms.slug = 'open-houses' 
    ORDER BY CAST(`post_title` AS UNSIGNED) ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can extract the decimal from the post_title. For example:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(`post_title`, ' ', 1) ASC
```